# How to launch Excel files in specific order via cmd?

Tags: excel, batch-file, cmd

I have 2 excel sheets which uses cmd to open them. 3 cmd is used.

One calls for sheet1 (OPENEXCEL1.bat).

```
"D:\APPS\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe" /e "C:\Users\Desktop\Sheet1.xlsx.
```

Second calls for the sheet2 (OPENEXCEL2.bat).

```
"D:\APPS\Microsoft Office\Office12\excel.exe" /e "C:\Users\Desktop\Sheet2.xlsx.
```

And the third acts as master calling for the previous 2 cmd.

```
start cmd /k call "OPENEXCEL1.bat"
start cmd /k call "OPENEXCEL2.bat"
```

Currently the 2 excel sheets are connected via VBA where sheet2 obtain data from sheet1. If sheet1 opens first before sheet2, the data transfer is fine. However if sheet2 opens before sheet1, an error will occur.

When I used this cmd, I noticed that the sequence of Excel sheet opens is different at times. Meaning that sometimes sheet1 opens first resulting in no problems, or sometimes sheet2 opens first resulting in problems as stated earlier.

Considering I'm new to cmd, is there a command that I can use to tell cmd that I want sheet1 to open 1st then proceed to sheet2?

Comment: it's more a timing problems than a logic problem. Use `timeout 5` between the two `start` commands, which gives Excel some time to open the first one before the second one is requested. (I know 5 seconds sounds very long, but you surely want to stay on the safe side.) Just out of curiosity: why do you use three batchfiles instead of only one? And why `/k`? And why not just `"C:\Users\Desktop\Sheet1.xlsx"` for opening?

Comment: bcoz the 2 excel files are using different versions of excel and I want them in different instances and using excel 07 and 10 each. when I tried to put both in a single cmd, it always defaults to 07. that's why I split it.

Comment: also thee timeout works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT: for this to work properly, make Excel start first at least once during a session, and maybe give it a timeout of a number of seconds before starting to open the actual files]

I just found a way of "explaining" to Excel to open a group of Excel files in the very specific order without using timeout (faster!), using the start command, simply by doubling the line of request for the initial file or group or files (no need to double the last one) I hope it helps!:

```
start "" "C:\Users\Desktop\Sheet1.xlsx"
start "" "C:\Users\Desktop\Sheet1.xlsx"

start"" "C:\Users\Desktop\Sheet2.xlsx"
```

EDIT: Alternatively, open Excel first if it was not opened yet during the system's session, it will give you more control on the order:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
timeout 1
start "" "C:\Users\Desktop\Sheet1.xlsx"
start "" "C:\Users\Desktop\Sheet1.xlsx"

start"" "C:\Users\Desktop\Sheet2.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephan said, there are some problems with your scripts. You can use only **1** script to fix the problems.

<kbd>OpenExcel.bat</kbd>

```
@echo off

"D:\Foo\Bar.xlsx"
timeout /t 5
"D:\Foo\Baz.xlsx"
```

This would open `Bar.xlsx`, wait 5 seconds, and open `Baz.xlsx`